# How can one check whether tax money is being effectively used by the government for improving a nation?

Tags: government, policy, measurement, indicators

Often people are critical of what they consider to be excessive taxation.  Are there any measures to actually check if they are excessive? What are indicators to check as to whether government is wisely spending the money?

Comment: Trump's opinion of wise spending comes nowhere near Biden's... which does one use, and which is truly better, more wise?

Comment: I would suggest rephrasing the question to finding out about *where* the money is being spent instead of *how* it is being spent. That way you can judge the expenditure yourself.

Comment: Are you asking whether the public can judge if the government was free of corruption and spent money as efficiently as possible to achieve its stated goals?  Or are you asking if the public can determine if the goals that were targeted for spending are helpful to the country?

Comment: This really is going to be opinion based as someone on one side of the political spectrum is going to have a different opinion about it being spent effectively then someone on the opposite side.

Comment: @JoeW The question is asking about a methodology of checking, not about the specific goals. Opinions about these goals do not come into play (while opinions about the appropriateness of the methods obviously do).

Comment: @ccprog Depending on what those goals are checking how it is being spent is going to differ.

Comment: FWIW, the activity of doing what the question asks is called a "performance audit." In the U.S., the General Accountability Office (GAO) fka the General Accounting Office, is the primary agency in charge of conducting such studies.

Comment: If you were to rephrase the question, would you ask "Are there any standard metrics that are correlated with both government spending and citizen quality of life?" If yes, then items like unemployment and inflation are often taken as gross measures of citizen quality of life, but I don't know of any specific government spending measure that are *standardized" as affecting unemployment or inflation. In fact, many political arguments are exactly this, whether a govt spending program will affect these things.

Comment: At a city government level, a calculation of the ratio of captial spend versus operational spend is in my view a wonderful way to see if tax is being reinvested in city infrastructure

Comment: *Often people criticize government by saying that when government increases taxes they're looting the people* — citation needed; apart from extremist libertarians representing less than 0.1% of the population, I've never seen this argument being made.  Can you please rephrase this hyperbolic statement in an otherwise interesting and relevant question?

Comment: Common sentiment in India, search up reactions to petrol prices tax hike @gerrit

Comment: [theGlobalEconomy.com](https://www.theglobaleconomy.com/indicators_list.php) lists over 400 indicators. While none of those indicators specifically addresses "government [] wisely spending [] money", it is nonetheless possible that some site, some where, may produce such an indicator, or that someone might creatively (even if subjectively) explain how some combination of *theGlobalEconomy* (or other) indicators may be used. Thus, the only opinion is that no such indicator can exist. Vote to reopen.

Comment: "improving a nation" is a subjective standard. (Extreme example: a Nazi would want to build gas chambers to "improve" the nation by killing whomever they find undesirable.) If you meant to ask something else, please clarify the Q.

Comment: This is one of the *core* question in politics:  are my taxes well-used/justified?.  The first (chrono) answer states that "wise" and "effective" are subjective and based on PoV.  That *answer* is not, itself *an opinion*, that's a fact.  The 2nd answer says many countries have audit processes:  also a fact.  The 3rd shows an example of a country that provides line item breakdowns.   None of these, factual, answers suffer all that much from being based on opinions.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: that's because they are not answering the Q as asked, but either frame-challenging it or answering some other (related) question. That doesn't make this Q good by SE standards.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: And if one wants to nitpick, one can add another frame challenge: [what is a nation?](https://www.rep.routledge.com/articles/thematic/nation-and-nationalism/v-1/sections/what-is-a-nation)

Comment: What would be wrong with looking at the budget statements as published by your government, showing both intended and actual spending? What else are you Asking about?

Answer (score 44):

One cannot, because *using money effectively* or *using money wisely* are [*normative statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normative_statement), which reflects one's subjective judgement about what is good for the country and its people. Thus, one can check (via the official government sources), whether the government did spend the required amount of tax money on education, healthcare or supporting war in Ukraine, but it is highly unlikely that all the taxpayers would agree that this spending was wise or effective.

Comment: Taxpayers vote for political parties in parliament (as well as regional governments),and one of functions of parliament is allocating money and checking how they are spent.

Comment: @alamar Not sure how this differs from what my answer says: one can check whether the money was spent as designated... but one cannot know, if this spending was *effective* or *wise* - it is a matter of belief.

Comment: There is a wide difference between "wisely", which would ask about all implications in the political sphere, or "effective", which asks about cause and effect only in the framework of stated reasons. I think the second one _does_ lend itself to "checking", at least that is what the term "audit" is all about.

Comment: @ccprog I think that effectiveness of a policy/spending is hard to define and measure. One can come up with some metrics, but this is just kicking the can down the road, because then it is a mater of belief that a particular metric really reflects effectiveness. E.g., the US has spent $8 billion on security assistance to Ukraine since February - was it effective? Perhaps, it prevented the collapse of the Ukrainian army... or perhaps it didn't make any difference and the things would be where they are now anyway.

Comment: There is a whole [branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_economics) of macroeconomics that kicks that particular can.

Comment: @RogerVadim Your parliament members could probably start a partisan audit of spendings. As another answer explains, audit is a well-defined process which checks for effectiveness of spendings. Audit is only a little bit opinionated.

Comment: @alamar - I'm pretty sure most audits don't check to see if the money was spent _effectively_, just that it was spent _as intended_.

Comment: @Bobson I'm pretty sure that the kind of consulting that Big Three do (or how many were there) would also check for efficiency. Yes, it is usually employed in commercial enterprises, but I'm not sure why it can't be used for govt spendings.

Comment: I feel like the OP is asking basically about "fraud, waste and abuse", which an audit could uncover. i.e., less about whether buying all the school rooms new desks was an effective expenditure, and more about whether that money went to the Prime Minster's cousin, who supplied the desks at a rate of $15,000 per desk.

Comment: @JamieB I admit that my answer is a bit tongue-in-cheek, but the OP is certainly not about what could be legally called fraud. It is about whether one really benefits or loses from particular taxes. In other words, whether a dollar in taxes imreturns to you as 2 dollars in terms of government services or whether it is lost money.

Comment: @alamar here is a quote about effectiveness of commercial enterprises: "Half the money I spend on advertising is wasted; the trouble is I don't know which half”.

Answer (score 21):

Most countries have an [institution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_audit_institution) that performs audits on the way government spends money, called for example Court of Audit, Board of Audit or Auditor-General. Normally, these institutions only have advisory powers and cannot directly intervene in the spending activities.

Whether this institution has enough independence to effectively control government spending obviously differs from country to country. Also, whether this institution constitutes a separate branch of government,  or is part of executive, legislative, or judiciary is a longstanding question answered differently everywhere.

But what you can hope for is that there will be regular public reports about the audit results. They can be the starting point for discussions about public spending. For example, in my country (Germany), the [annual report](https://www.bundesrechnungshof.de/en/audit-reports/products/annual-reports) of the [Bundesrechnungshof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundesrechnungshof) sparks a discussion in the media each year, where government officials that were criticised in the report have to defend their spending behavior in detail.

Comment: It should be added that these spending auditions probably only look for obvious spending mistakes. Besides there is still corruption and maybe general misallocations and not very efficient spending or too much bureaucracy maybe. There are more types of inefficient spending. Even privatizations could be seen as inefficient spending (because they may become expensive in the long run).

Comment: Don't underestimate the breadth of what these institutions take into focus. For example this [list of special reports](https://www.bundesrechnungshof.de/en/audit-reports/products/special-reports) contains a number of issues related to targeting funding to achieve stated goals, prevention of shadow budgets, inappropriate legislation and others.

Answer (score 10):

In Australia we are given a [tax receipt](https://www.ato.gov.au/individuals/your-tax-return/check-the-progress-of-your-tax-return/tax-receipt/) from the federal government that shows what our taxes were spent on. Breaking down where each of my personal tax dollars was spent. I guess what it is spent on is different to how effectively that money is being spent, but at least it allows you to see if where the money is being directed to by the current government aligns to your expectations and can impact who you may vote for.

[Join others](https://www.reddit.com/r/interestingasfuck/comments/cl9jvt/australian_government_outlines_how_my_taxes_are/) and demand your government does similar

[image]

Comment: Spending 0.7% of the budget on immigration doesn't sounds so bad until you learn they spent $40m to resettle a single person. `In effect, people accused of no crime are warehoused in appalling conditions in arbitrary and indefinite detention. Dozens of countries, the United Nations, and rights groups including Amnesty International and Human Rights Watch, have documented and condemned the illegal detention.` https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/aug/10/a-short-history-of-nauru-australias-dumping-ground-for-refugees To understand those numbers, one needs to do a bit of research.

Comment: I think the numbers by themselves are rather meaningless. When determining if something is an effective use of money one should not just look at the amount of money spent, but also at the results. Resettling a single human should not cost $40m. I think everyone can agree on that regardless of political affiliation.

Comment: The UK government does something similar.

Comment: And this is probably the issue - commentators are commentating on 0.7% of budget and saying $40M is a lot - how much of the immigration budget is that? But ignoring the order of magnitude budgets for Welfare and Defence etc.

Comment: The Australian "tax receipt" is literally just a simple breakdown of the disposal of total government revenue. Everyone gets the same bar chart, the numbers are just scaled by your personal tax amount, in a fairly trivial calculation. They were introduced as a rhetorical device by a government keen on cutting welfare and services to reduce debt, hoping that people would be more outraged by seeing it as "personally" spending $7,000 than by seeing it as collectively spending 200 billion dollars. "Demand your government does similar" feels like a waste of time, to me.

Comment: The UK Government also publishes comprehensive statistics at https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/national-statistics-release.

Answer (score 0):

One begins by trying to come up with definitions of "effectively" and "improving" (to elaborate on Roger Vadim's excellent answer).

Often "effectively" seems to translate to "spent by our political party".

Take for example law enforcement.  Possible spending / actions include:

- Attempts to make people who would otherwise become criminals into productive citizens:

  - Job training
  - Improving education
  - Attempts to reduce poverty,
- Performing studies to determine what measures have been or are predicted to be effective in reducing future crime
- Attempts to improve prisons to help reform inmates / lower recidivism
- Hiring more police officers
- Decriminalization of some non-violent offenses (fewer inmates, people remain more employable vs. becoming felons)
- Converting parts of police services to e.g. conflict resolution experts
- Passing legislation to 'get tough on crime'
- Passing legislation to attempt to improve the small business climate
- Passing pro-corporate legislation to make more jobs

Every intervention will have its effects, unintended side-effects, proponents and critics.